# VBA for Word, crop image to circle

Tags: vba, image, ms-word

i want to crop all images in my Word-document to a circle shape.
My current VBA is not doing anything. I am not quite sure how to do this. I found some VBA examples but not for Word (Power-Point)
My VBA at the moment is looking like this:

After looking more into it it seems my proble is that the images are inlineshapes?
Is there still any possible solution?

```
Sub Circles()

Dim allShapes As ShapeRange 
Dim myShape As Shape

Set allShapes = Selection.ShapeRange

For Each myShape In allShapes
    
  
With myShape
    .AutoShapeType = msoShapeOval
    .Height = InchesToPoints(0.18)
    .Width = InchesToPoints(0.18)
    End With
    
Next myShape
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Cropping a picture to a circle is actually filling a shapes background with a picture.

Here is the code for doing that:

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape msoShapeOval, 100, 100, 100, 100
ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).Fill.UserPicture ("Y:\Pictures\Mk45 Gun Proj_Blast.jpg")
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input :) my problem here is that i don't have the image path, it's just a word document of 50+ images that I got from a friend. If I understand your code correctly that wouldn't work?